# Evaluating constants without compiling using gcc for cffi

Tags: gcc, python-cffi

I'm trying to write a python interface to a shared library. The library has headers provided, and so I'd like to be able to used them as the `cdef` input.

I realise that I need to preprocess the headers before I load them into CFFI. However, the library headers have code something like this:

```
#define ONE 1
char something[250+ONE];
```

which comes out of the preprocessor (`gcc -E`) as

```
char something[250+1];
```

CFFI complains that the 251 is not a simple numerical constant (which as far as parsing is concerned, is true). Is there a way to make GCC evaluate these integer constants at preprocessor time?

(Of course, I realise I can just manually change the header file, but I'd like to see if I can use the header files that are shipped with the library)